# How to get checked values of all other Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript

I have created this code example for selecting items from radio button among the given `data`. In this, when we click on any input, its value is console logged, but I am not able to figure out on how to console log other fieldset selected values as well, so for eg:- If I select, `Blue` it will console log `Blue`, but I want it to console log something like: - `Blue` and the rest are `S`. Other checked values from another position of data should also be console logged.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```js
const something = document.getElementById('something');

const data = [{
  name: 'Color',
  values: ['Blue', 'Red', 'Black']
}, {
  name: 'size',
  values: ['S', 'M', 'L']
}]

const variOptions1 = data[0].values[0];
const variOptions2 = data[1].values[0];
something.innerHTML = data.map((modalVari, indexVariposition) => {
 return   `
<fieldset class="modal-variant-form">
    <legend class="modal-variant-title">${modalVari.name}:</legend>
   
    ${modalVari.values.map((varival, variIndx) => (`
               <input type="radio" id="variant-${indexVariposition}-${variIndx}" name="${modalVari.name}" value="${varival}"${variOptions1 == varival || variOptions2 == varival  ? 'checked' : ''}>
               <label for="variant-${indexVariposition}-${variIndx}">
                   ${varival}
               </label>
           `)).join("")}
   
</fieldset>
`
}).join('');


for (var h = 0; h < data.length; h++) {
  const fieldFirst = data[h].name;
  const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${fieldFirst}"]`);
  for (const radioButton of radioButtons) {
    radioButton.addEventListener('change', showSelected);
  }

  function showSelected(e) {

    if (this.checked) {
      console.log(`You selected ${this.value}`);

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="something"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.getElementsByName('color').forEach(
 function(elem) {
  if(!elem.checked) {
   //your code if the radio button not checked
    }
   }
  )
```

In this case, you should set all of the radio buttons that you want to see `name` attribute to `color`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your script and make it loop over all
radio buttons. Only when a button is `.checked` its value is printed:

```js
const something = document.getElementById('something');

const data = [{
  name: 'Color',
  values: ['Blue', 'Red', 'Black']
}, {
  name: 'size',
  values: ['S', 'M', 'L']
}]

something.innerHTML = data.map((modalVari, indexVariposition) => {
  return `
    <fieldset class="modal-variant-form">
        <legend class="modal-variant-title">${modalVari.name}:</legend>
       
        ${modalVari.values.map((varival, variIndx) => (`
                   <input type="radio" id="variant-${indexVariposition}-${variIndx}" name="${modalVari.name}" value="${varival}">
                   <label for="variant-${indexVariposition}-${variIndx}">
                       ${varival}
                   </label>
               `)).join("")}
       
    </fieldset>
    `
}).join('');

const radioButtons=[...something.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]")];

something.addEventListener("click",ev=> {
 if (ev.target.type!=="radio") return;
 console.log(Object.fromEntries(radioButtons.filter(rb=>rb.checked)
  .map(rb=>[rb.name,rb.value])))
})
```

```html
<div id="something"></div>
```